# Indexed Unions of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Find $\bigcup_{B\in A}B$,  where $A=\left\{\left[1,1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right ]: 
> n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$.

I'm not sure how to do this. I think I don't understand the notation. $B$ is not stated in the question, so how do you know if $B\in A?$

Comment: What's $[1+1/n]$?

Comment: For example, if $A=\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, then $\bigcup_{B\in A}B=\{1\}\cup\{1,2\}$, where $B$ runs over the elements of $A$.

Comment: The notation means the union of all elements of $A$. Note that the elements of $A$ are sets themselves (though your description of $A$ is most likely a typo).

Comment: Edited the typo

Comment: Possibly not well-defined if you take $\mathbb{N}$ to include $0$, unless you are working on the extended real line or are just assuming that $\left[1,\infty\right]=\left[1,\infty\right)$.

Comment: Assume $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$[1,1+\frac1n]$ is the closed interval with endpoints $1$ and $1+\frac1n$. Since $1+\frac1n \le 1+1=2$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and equality does occur (at $n=1$) the required union is the closed interval $[1,2]$.

Answer (score 2):

Much like when we write $\sum\limits_{n=1}^5 n^2$ we mean that $n$ is the variable whose values go from $1$ to $5$, and when we write $\sum\limits_{n<k}n^3$ we mean that $n$ is the variable whose values are  $1,\ldots,k-1$; similarly when we write $$\bigcup_{B\in A}B,$$ we mean that $B$ is the variable whose values go over all the members of $A$. If you want to write it in a notation which may make more sense to *you*, then perhaps this might help: $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\left[1,1+\frac1n\right]=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[1,1+\frac1n\right].$$

To find out the answer, by the way, note that $A$ is a family of $\subseteq$-decreasing sets which has a least element.

Answer (score 1):

The notation $\cup_{B \in A} B$ means take the union of all sets in $A$.

If you let $B_n = [1,1+\frac{1}{n}]$, you can see that $B_{n+1} \subset B_n$ for all $n$. Hence $\cup_{B \in A} B = [1,1+1] = 1,2]$.